# Wrong nodes connection in a directed graph with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing a directed graph with nodes in static position using d3.js library. 
Currently I am having 3 nodes, and I want to connect the two computers with the printer. The edges are set to different positions as seen in this image:

[image]

How can i make the lines connect the nodes based on the nodes position? 
Here is the code I have so far.

```
var width = 640,
    height = 400;
var nodes = [
    { x:   184.53020651496104, y: 0, id: 0, url:             
              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh- 
              cl/32/Hardware-My-Computer-3-icon.png"},
    { x:   100, y: 150, id: 1, url: 
           "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh- 
           cl/32/Hardware-My-Computer-3-icon.png" },
    { x:   width/3, y: height/2, id: 2, url: 
           "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh- 
           cl/32/Hardware-Printer-Blue-icon.png" },
 ];
 var links = [
    { source: 1, target: 2 },
    { source: 0, target: 2 }
 ];
 var graph = d3.select('#graph');
 var svg = graph.append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height);
 var force = d3.layout.force()
               .size([width, height])
               .nodes(nodes)
               .links(links);
 force.linkDistance(width/2);
 var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
               .data(links)
               .enter().append('line')
               .attr('class', 'link');
 var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
               .data(nodes)
               .enter().append("image")
               .attr("xlink:href", d=> d.url)
               .attr("x", d=> d.x)
               .attr("y", d=> d.y)
               .attr("width", 30)
               .attr("height", 30)
               .attr('class', 'node');
  force.on('end', function() {
      node.attr('r', width/25)
          .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });
      link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });
   });
   force.start();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are positioning the nodes on force end with `cx` and `cy` *(and `r`)* attributes which would work for circles but not icons - you need to position with `x` and `y` properties (as you do initially, which explains the mismatch).